# Исключение питон: не известно имя "datetime"

Tags: python, функции, библиотеки, библиотека

Я делал модуль - улучшенная библиотека time. Я остановился на функции str_cur_weekday. Эта функция использует метод now() из библиотеки datetime. Вроде импортировал модуль datetime, но ошибка говорит, что не знает имени datetime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    str_cur_weekday()
  File "C:\Users\vanya\Desktop\UTP.py", line 53, in 
str_cur_weekday
    now = datetime.now()
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

Вот весь код:

```
SECOND = 1
HOUR = 3600
MINUTE = 60
DAY = 86400

WeekList = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

REPLY_IN_REQUIREMENTS = '''Basic requirements not met. 
Go to the command line and enter the text: 
pip install time
pip install datetime'''

class REQUIREMENTS:        
         def check(self, check_true):
            try:
                if check_true == 0:
                    check_true_no_attribute = None
                    from time import sleep
                    import datetime
                    import sys
                    check_true_no_attribute = 1
                if check_true_no_attribute == 1:
                    pass
            except ModuleNotFoundError:
                for i in range(1, 100):
                    print('Fatal % i: ' + REPLY_IN_REQUIREMENTS)
                    sys.exit()
b = REQUIREMENTS()
check_true = 0


def wait_in_seconds(secs):
    b.check(0)
    sleep(secs)
    
def wait_in_minutes(minutes):
    b.check(0)
    for i in range(0, minutes):
        sleep(MINUTE)

def wait_in_hours(hours):
    b.check(0)
    for i in range(0, hours):
        sleep(HOUR)

def wait_in_days(days):
    b.check(0)
    for i in range(0, days):
        sleep(DAY)

def str_cur_weekday():
    b.check(0)
    now = datetime.now()
    current_weekday = now.isoweekday()
    cd_kill_one = current_weekday - 1
    str_current_weekday = WeekList[cd_kill_one]
    print(str_current_weekday)
```

Пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему!

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Вы импортировали внутри метода check, вот оно только там внутри и существует

Comment: Хорошо, alecsandr barakin

Comment: @andreymal  А вдруг это какой-нибудь micropython, где ничего нет? (на самом деле я не знаю, но мало ли) )

Comment: @CrazyElf не думаю, что кто-то будет делать pip install datetime на micropython)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В верху файла добавьте код:

```
import datetime
```

Исправьте код:

```
now = datetime.now()
```

На:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: Проверил - работает! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Либо делайте импорты обычным для питона образом в самом начале программы:

```
import datetime
...
```

Либо объявляйте `datetime` глобальной переменной:

```
class REQUIREMENTS:        
         def check(self, check_true):
            global datetime # <-- теперь будет видно в основной части программы
            try:
                if check_true == 0:
                    check_true_no_attribute = None
                    from time import sleep
                    import datetime
```

На самом деле импорты много ресурсов не отнимают, поэтому кроме специфических совсем уж случаев лучше их просто делать в начале программы.

Comment: Спасибо, CrazyElf